# I am not getting desired output from Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api

I am using the php sdk provided by the dropbox. But I am not able to get all the content of the user account...
I am getting the content of only "App//"
Can anyone solve this?

I hope i have explained my problem correctly.

Please feel free to ask for any info.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the app permissions here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide.

My guess would be that you created an app with App Folder permissions. (When you created the app, you clicked "Yes" when asked "Can your app be limited to its own folder?") If you  need different permissions, you'll have to create a new app.

Comment: you are right... My permission type of app is appfolder...
Can I change this permission type? If yes, How and If No,
What shall I need to take care while creating a new app?

Comment: No, as I said, you'll need to create a new app. Just choose the permissions that you want this time.